# How should I write a placeholder in a phrase I show?

Tags: discussion, answers

Suppose I want to show how the verb *learn* is used, and I want to show that it is used as:

- Learn [something]
- Learn from [something/somebody]
- Learning [something] from doing [something]

What I wrote between brackets are placeholders. Is it fine if I write them so, or is it better if I write them in italic?

- Learn *something*
- Learn from *something/somebody*
- Learning *something* from doing *something*

Comment: Rather than using a placeholder at all, why not write the sentence in context and embolden the part that you're interested in, for example: ***Learn** from a textbook*,  ***Learn** how to swim* etc.

Comment: If I don't use a placeholder, I should make an example for each variant. If I write _learn from a textbook_, it is not clear that _learn from somebody_ is also acceptable.

Comment: @kiamluno: That is precisely why I would avoid using a placeholder. For example most answers about learn [X] will give an answer that doesn't hold for idioms like "learn the ropes". Similarly people who ask "does raining [X] and [Y]" have a special meaning, the answer is *not usually*, unless [X] happens to be cats and [Y] happens to be dogs. By making your question more generic than you need it to be, you're making it harder for answerers to write solid, practical and specific answers to your problem.

Comment: It is clear that not everything can be the direct object of a verb, even if it grammatically makes sense. I would not use placeholders for "it rains cats and dogs," nor would I use a generic placeholder like [X]; in fact, the example I used is "learn [something]" which at least excludes "learn me."

Comment: The question is not more generic that I would need it to be. It is simply asking how I can make it clear that _somebody_ is not the exact word that needs to follow _learn_, but _learn_ can be followed by "cooking polenta," for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have said, if at all possible, don't use placeholders: very often, a specific question has unique features that would make a generic answer inapplicable. If you're looking for a general answer, use multiple examples rather than placeholders. (Make your examples as different from each other as you can, so you have a better likelihood of hitting all the edge cases.)

If you absolutely have to use placeholders, I think the square bracket notation is better: italics are often used to emphasize the word you're asking about, so it would be confusing to see it used for a word you specifically *don't* care about. It's also good to make the fact that it's a placeholder explicit, by using the word "placeholder" (or "[insert word here]" or some such) instead of a pronoun like "somebody" or "something", because the latter sometimes have special rules.